# Getting error when launching flutter apps in simulators

Tags: flutter

When I open up an IOS simulator to launch my apps, it fails. Before it used to work fine. I get the following error:

```
Xcode build done.                                           12.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
Could not find an option named "DartDefines".
Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I am suspecting this error is due to not enough storage on my computer. Is that possible? Or is there any other problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue after upgrading the flutter. 
You must be using flutter channel beta
Try switching it to:

```
flutter channel dev 
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: Yes I upgraded flutter and it did this

Comment: Ok I will try to do that