# Could not find an option named "DartDefines"

Tags: ios, flutter

When I open up an IOS simulator to launch my flutter apps, it fails. Before it used to work fine. I get the following error:

```
Xcode build done.                                           122.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Could not find an option named "DartDefines".
    Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I tried the following

[Getting error when launching flutter apps in simulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61873099/getting-error-when-launching-flutter-apps-in-simulators).

Comment: Can you add the output of `flutter doctor`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and I've fixed it by running two command.
Please try, hope it help.

flutter channel dev

flutter upgrade

Good luck!